# php order that nested loops run in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a piece of code that retrieves data from the Facebook api. Basically what happens is I loop over all the posts in our own database. For each posts it will try to get all shares for that post from the Facebook api. The Facebook api retrieves an object with a next link for the next batch of shares for that posts and it will keep looping till it gets all shares and go on to the next post.

The code looks as follows (Note that this is not my actual code because it has way to many things going on that are not important or needed for my question):

```
// SELECT all posts from my database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       try {
          //this is our api call to get all share posts
          $response = $fb-get($row['postId'] . "someApiEndPointForSharedPosts");

          //start processing the response for the post
          processFeed($response);
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           //There is no response or there is another error
           echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
       }
    }
}

function processFeed($shares){

   //Go through all shares in the response and do some modification and storage etc
   foreach($shares as $share){
       //Do something with the share
   }

   //Facebook sdk method to get the next batch of shares for the post (if there are any left)
   $nextFeed = fb->next($shares);

   //If there are more shares run this function again with the new batch
   if(isset($nextFeed)){
      processFeed($nextFeed);
   }
}
```

Now my question is. Will the code run in the following order:

1. Select all post
2. Do the api call for the first post (which returns an response)
3. Start process feed with the response for the first post
4. Check if there is a next feed for the first post
5. If there is run process feed agian till there is no next feed left for the first post
6. Start over by doing the api call for the second post and do the above process agian.

Comment: Yes, your code will run in the given order.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: My bad. But that is indeed the case. Just a typo in the sample code. The problem is that for some reason I get way more posts when just querying for 1 post. So this with limit 1 on the post query would result in 20 shares for that post for example, but when I run it without a limit it could give me only 10 shares for that same post. So im trying to figure out if my code is doing some wierd stuff or that the fb api is limiting my requests

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that aswell. But lets say I call ProcessFeed($shareData1) and directly ProcessFeed($shareData2) that wouldnt cause a problem right? And there are no global vars or anything outside the function used besided the data which I pass to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163199/discussion-between-philipp-maurer-and-merijn-dk).